# How to query on multiple fields in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

i have tried the multiple field query and it works fine. But I would like to know what other options are generally used to query multiple fields in elasticsearch?

Answer (score 2):

Structured queries with multiple terms, for finding exact values, the same as SQL

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_finding_multiple_exact_values.html

```
"bool" : {
                    "must" : [
                        { "term" : { "tags" : "search" } }, 
                        { "term" : { "tag_count" : 1 } } 
                    ]
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

For example, consider following sql query,

```
SELECT product
FROM   products
WHERE  (price = 20 OR productID = "XHDK-A-1293-#fJ3")
  AND  (price != 30)
```

In these situations, you will need the bool filter. This is a compound filter that accepts other filters as arguments, combining them in various Boolean combinations.

The Query DSL would be,

```
GET /my_store/products/_search
{
   "query" : {
      "filtered" : { 
         "filter" : {
            "bool" : {
              "should" : [
                 { "term" : {"price" : 20}}, 
                 { "term" : {"productID" : "XHDK-A-1293-#fJ3"}} 
              ],
              "must_not" : {
                 "term" : {"price" : 30} 
              }
           }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Follow the below link for documentation
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/combining-filters.html